# Any way to use CRUD in Wagtail(Django) without reload page?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-snippet

I'm talking about a table with data from a model (like Django). So that the visitor can make changes to the table fields without reloading the page. The description of the framework shows several options for developing such a solution in WAGTAIL

1. make a snippet and link it to a table. There will be a filter option. But I still could not understand whether it is possible to make changes to the table cells without reloading.
   In that case, I suppose to use something like that:

```
    @register_snippet    
    class Mapping(models.Model):
            map_code = models.OneToOneField('Map', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='curr_map_code', primary_key=True)
            date_begin = models.DateField()
            class Meta:
                managed = True
                db_table = 'MAPPING'
```

2. Using the STREAMFIELD add a TABLEBLOCK. the documentation says that it is based on [handsontable 6.2.2](https://handsontable.com/blog/handsontable-6.2.2-released) and it has the ability to make changes without rebooting page with table.
   [image: handsontable 6.2.2 can edit]
   But I cant achive managed to generate table data based on the Django
   model and possibility for user edit. That is, I can manually enter values in the cells in the
   admin panel. But in the custom view, there is no such possibility at
   all.

Try to use something like that:

```
    class Mapping(models.Model):
        map_code = models.OneToOneField('Map', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='curr_map_code', primary_key=True)
        date_begin = models.DateField()
        class Meta:
            managed = True
            db_table = 'MAPPING'
```

```
class HomePage(Page):     
        body = StreamField(
        [
            ('Mapping',TableBlock(table_options=new_table_options)
        ],
        null=True,
        blank = True,
        use_json_field=True,
        )
        content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
            FieldPanel('body'),
        ]
```

Please let me know which option is possible or may be something else. Thanks in advance!